# How to identify and extract simple nested tokens with a BNF lexer?

Tags: lex, bnf, marpa

I have no idea how to get documentation about this. I just discovered that most of the compilers are using the Backus–Naur Form to describe a language.

From the `Marpa::R2` perl package, get this simple example that parse arithmetic strings such as `42 * 1 + 7`:

```
:default ::= action => [name,values]
lexeme default = latm => 1

Calculator ::= Expression action => ::first

Factor ::= Number action => ::first
Term ::=
    Term '*' Factor action => do_multiply
    | Factor action => ::first
Expression ::=
    Expression '+' Term action => do_add
    | Term action => ::first
Number ~ digits
digits ~ [\d]+
:discard ~ whitespace
whitespace ~ [\s]+
```

I would like to modify this in order to recursively parse an XML like sample such as:

```
<foo>
    Some content here 
    <bar>
        I am nested into foo
    </bar>
    A nested block was before me.
</foo>
```

And express it into something like:

```
>(Some content here)
>>(I am nested into foo)
>(A nested block was before me)
```

Where I may use this function:

```
sub block($content, $level) {
    for each $content line
        $line = (">" x $level).$content
    return $content
}
```

Was would be a good start for me?

Comment: There is an open-source Marpa-powered XML parser -- https://github.com/jddurand/MarpaX-Languages-XML-AST

Comment: and https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Marpa-R2/html/pod/HTML.pod can help too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open-source [Marpa-powered XML parser](https://github.com/jddurand/MarpaX-Languages-XML-AST).